# Send JSON do not redirect

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to let users know if their username is taken. I want to do this **without** redirecting or refreshing the page. (It's a long sign up page) 
My code below works to check if the username is taken but in order to get the res.json message it redirects. How would I display the message if the username is taken or not without redirecting?

Thanks!

```
    app.get('/usercheck', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({username: req.query.username}, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        var message;
        if(user) {
          console.log(user)
            message = "user exists";
            console.log(message)
        } else {
            message= "user doesn't exist";
            console.log(message)
        }
        res.json({message: message});
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you use this from client side? I mean you need to use AJAX call so the question is do you use AJAX or you submit a form?

Comment: Total shot in the dark without seeing your client side code, but sounds like your form action is pointing to `/usercheck` and whatever event you are using to fire your request on the client side is submitting the form. You need to be sorting this in your AJAX on your client side.